# Shopify API getting order by name or order_number

Tags: cakephp, shopify, restful-url

I'm using a plugin for **CakePHP** to make the calls to obtain certain orders. I can call all orders with certain fields, but I was wondering how would I have to make the call to get the orders with a certain name or `order_number`? Here is the source for the call to **Shopify**. Its already authenticated and everything:

```
public function call($method, $path, $params=array())
    {
        if (!$this->isAuthorized())
            return;
        $password = $this->is_private_app ? $this->secret : md5($this->secret.$this->ShopifyAuth->token);
        $baseurl = "https://{$this->api_key}:$password@{$this->ShopifyAuth->shop_domain}/";
    
        $url = $baseurl.ltrim($path, '/');
        $query = in_array($method, array('GET','DELETE')) ? $params : array();
        $payload = in_array($method, array('POST','PUT')) ? stripslashes(json_encode($params)) : array();
    $request_headers = in_array($method, array('POST','PUT')) ? array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", 'Expect:') : array();
    $request_headers[] = 'X-Shopify-Access-Token: ' . $this->ShopifyAuth->token;
        list($response_body, $response_headers) = $this->Curl->HttpRequest($method, $url, $query, $payload, $request_headers);
    $this->last_response_headers = $response_headers;
    $response = json_decode($response_body, true);

        if (isset($response['errors']) or ($this->last_response_headers['http_status_code'] >= 400))
            throw new ShopifyApiException($method, $path, $params, $this->last_response_headers, $response);

        return (is_array($response) and (count($response) > 0)) ? array_shift($response) : $response;
    }
    
    private function shopApiCallLimitParam($index)
    {
        if ($this->last_response_headers == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        $params = explode('/', $this->last_response_headers['http_x_shopify_shop_api_call_limit']);
        return (int) $params[$index];
    }
```

...and the code that makes the `GET` call:

```
// I only want the id and title of the collections
            $fields = "fields=name,id,status,financial_status,fulfillment_status,billing_address,customer";
            // get list of collections
            $custom_collections = $this->ShopifyAPI->call('GET', "/admin/orders.json", $fields);
            $this->set('collections', $custom_collections);
```

I think I'm missing the place where I can put the conditions for the call to get certain orders. I've already read the API documentation but can't seem to get the answer.

I've tried putting the `?name=%231001` on the url after `.json` to try and get the order **#1001**, but it brings back a empty array.

Then I tried `order_number=1001` but it brings me every order with as well 1001 D: This is really confusing, Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well I found out that you can actually get the order using the name or order_number. Its another property that is not listed on the documentation for some reason. But in the URL, if your using another language, all you have to add in the GET is admin/order.json?name=%2310001&status=any this is to get the order 10001 so just add the order_number after the %23.  I saw this on a forum in Shopify university, I was just implementing this wrong on my code. If your using the CakePhp shopify plugin like me all I did was add on the $field the ?name=%23". number ."&status=any";

Ill leave the code here:

```
    $this->layout = 'main';

$order_number = "18253";

$fields = "name=%23". $order_number ."&status=any";

$order = $this->ShopifyAPI->call('GET', "/admin/orders.json", $fields);
   if (!empty($order)) {
     $this->set('order', $order);

     } else {
       $this->Session->setFlash('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button> No existe el numero de orden ingresado.','default',array('class' => 'alert alert-danger alert-dismissible', 'type' => 'alert'));
     }
```

Hope this helps someone :P

Comment: If you have to manually escape the # in your query string, that means the then the api call is passing in raw input. The real fix should be in your HttpRequest class which should be url encoding query params passed into it. http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: Actually Im encoding the # cause its a prefix our store uses for the name of the orders. Others might have other prefix to the order number. And encoding the # on the http would be more work cause not every time would I be sending the name on the fields for the ShopfyAPI to make the call.

Comment: I understand name=#000000 is the format. What I'm saying is if you have to manually escape a value (using %23 instead of #), that means any value in your query string that has a reserved character( space,#?&) isn't going to be encoded correctly. Fixing this encoding issue in the ->call() method means you don't have to worry about special characters in your "$fields" data. http_build_query() can take care of that detail for you.

Comment: When doing a GET request on admin/orders.json?name=1234, you do not need to provide the #, escaped or otherwise. The Shopify order search api ignores it. So doing GET admin/orders.json?name=#1234 & admin/ordes.json?name=1234 returns the exact same result.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to escape the #, just remove the # and make the API call

Like so
https://myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-01/orders.json?name=12345678&status=any

for order: #12345678, it will return the exact same response

Comment: Answer to "how to get a shopify order with the order number" "without the external order id"